# How can I bundle an ES6 JavaScript framework for web usage, allowing access to defined functions and classes?

Tags: javascript

How can I bundle a JS framework written in es6 to work on the web? Tools like esbuild make it so that you can bundle code to run on the web, but I can't use any of the functions or classes in my files, since all the code is inside `(() => { here })();`. Is there any way to run a command (or several) to bundle all my code, and its dependencies, into web friendly code where I can use the functions and classes I define?

For example:

```js
// app.js
import {package} from package

function a (param) {
    console.log(package(param))
}

export default { a }
```

If I take the above code and run `command app.js` (or any other command), it should produce a minified js file (`bundle.js`) with the source code of package and should allow me, assuming I've declared `<script src='bundle.js'></script>`, to execute `a()` in a script tag.

Comment: You just import the package from another ES module...

Comment: You can configure all of these tools to output a script, a library, a module, etc…